Compiling libqemu from QEMU Source: Seeking Up-to-Date Instructions
I'm currently facing challenges compiling libqemu from the QEMU source. Despite extensive searches on GitHub, I've been unable to locate any functional projects, which is surprising. The closest codes I found, https://gist.github.com/th0rex/946c12e04c7ded43d12abbc92c9b5363  and https://github.com/cloudbase/libqemu-build, appears outdated and incompatible with the latest QEMU version.
I've managed to compile QEMU from its source code, but I stumbled upon the concept of linking. It seems to be a crucial aspect of the library compilation process.
While I've referred to the QEMU documentation, it lacks detailed instructions on compiling libqemu independently. Could someone offer guidance on successfully compiling libqemu from the QEMU source within a contemporary environment?
The code by th0rex seemed great because it offers the option to select the specific build of QEMU instead of having to compile every version. This significantly reduces build time in most cases.
I'm seeking a script that avoids complex hacks, as they may become incompatible with future updates to the QEMU source code. I prefer a solution that maintains compatibility and reliability over time.
I believe the process may not require many additional steps, as building QEMU as a library shouldn't significantly differ from building the entire QEMU application.
Thank you in advance for any assistance provided, it means a lot for me.

Building parts of QEMU into a separate library is not in any way supported by upstream QEMU. The only supported option is to build executables. As you have found, a few people have done some hacky things in the past to try to produce a library, but this is very fragile and liable to break when upstream QEMU makes changes that rearrange how it builds things.
(There used to be an upstream "libqemu" a very long time ago, but it was removed over a decade ago.)

Thank you for your response. I'm curious about the level of similarity between the libqemu build derived from the qemu source and the executable. Does this essentially expose qemu's internal functions?

Looking at the scripts you've linked they just shove a bunch of object files into the libqemu.a. This is directly exposing QEMU's internals, yes.
